# Cannot create a new JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am making Pong in Java, and I have already implemented the main game, but I also want to have a menu screen pop up at the beginning.  I created the menu screen, but I can't figure out how to start the game when I press the "start game" button.  I have a class that contains my main method:

```java
public class main {
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        PongRunner runner = new PongRunner();
        runner.menuScreen();


      //System.out.println(""+display.getHeight()+" "+display.getWidth());

    }

}
```

And I also have a class for running the menu and main game:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class PongRunner extends JFrame{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MLG Pong");
    public PongRunner()
    {

    }

    public void menuScreen()
    {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        frame.add(menu);
        frame.setSize(1280,720);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }

    public void startGame()
    {
        frame.removeAll();
        game game = new game();
        frame.add(game);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to make it so when I press the button to start the game, I will call the startGame() method and clear, or "delete", the menu JPanel inside my JFrame and replace it with the JPanel from my game class.  Here is the actionListener from the menu class:

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("startgame")){
            redraw = false;
            //System.out.println("test");
            PongRunner runner = new PongRunner();
            runner.startGame();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Check out CardLayout - it will let you display one JPanel at a time and switch between them.  Here's the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new `PongRunner` in your action listener. Use the initially created instance.

Also, don't use `add` with your `JFrame` use the method `setContentPane` to set the *main* content of the frame. So you need `PongRunner` and `Menu` to be subclasses of `Container` which every swing JComponent is).

So the code should be like :

```
public class main {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    PongRunner runner = new PongRunner();
    runner.menuScreen();
  }
}

public class game extends ... { // should extends at least Container
}

public class Menu extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  private PongRunner theRunner;
  public Menu(PongRunner p) {
    theRunner = p;
    JButton b = new JButton("Start");
    b.setActionCommand("startgame");
    this.add(b);
    b.addActionListener(this);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("startgame")) {
      theRunner.startGame();
    }
  }
}

public class PongRunner extends JFrame {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("MLG Pong");
  public void menuScreen() {
    Menu menu = new Menu(this);
    frame.setContentPane(menu);
    frame.setSize(1280,720); // don't use such a thing, set the preferred size of the contentPane to a desired value
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
  }
  public void startGame() {
    frame.setContentPane(new game());
    frame.pack();
  }    
}
```

Comment: When creating a new Menu in the menuScreen method, should there be a `(this)` as an argument since the Menu constructor takes PongRunner as an argument?